# Move emails with procmail if it matches from sender

Tags: email, filter, procmail

as im using different email clients to read/send my mails i want to setup procmail to move my emails to a the folder which is normally done by Thunderbird filter feature.

I know that i can do it by using the following code for procmail in my email users .procmailrc file:

```
:0:
* ^From:.test@host.name.com
myfolder
```

But i have a list of about 50 email adresses which i would like to move to that specific "myfolder".

So by using

```
:0:
* ^From:.first@mail.com
* ^From:.second@mail.com
jimsmail
```

doesnt help, because procmail interprets them by using the AND operater. So the code above would be true if From is first@... AND second@..., which will never be true.

So how do i use the OR operator.

Actually i have a simple text file where all email adresses are.
Would be cool to have a feature where procmail ready in that file and checks if From matches with at least one of the lines in the file, the moves email to "myfolder".

Something like

```
 :0:
 * ^From:file(email.txt)
 myfolder
```

Does anybode if this or something similar is possible.
I dont want to add these 3 lines 50 times in my procmailrc file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.
With this solution im able to use a simple email text file holding all email addresses in each in one line.

The code in my .procmailrc is as follows:

```
EMAILFILE=/path/to/my/emailfile
FROM=`formail -xFrom: | sed -e 's/ *(.*)//; s/>.*//; s/.*[:<] *//'`
:0
* ? fgrep -qxis $FROM $EMAILFILE
myfolder
```

Answer (score 2):

Procmail uses regexps, so you can separate addresses with the `|` character.

```
:0:
* ^From:.((first|second|third)@mail.com|(fourth|fifth)@othermail.com)
myfolder
```

would work. Could get a little messy with fifty all on one line, mind...

Comment: hm that one doesnt work.
in the logs it shows no error. but somehow there is no match.

the line looks like this:
      * ^From:.(email.info@domain.com|second.email@domain.com)